# Browse JAR files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm not very experienced with Java or Eclipse, but I am trying to browse and decompile some jar files within Eclipse.  I went ahead and grabbed [JD-Eclipse](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse) for opening .class files, but I can't get Eclipse to let me browse the .jar files.  I read that the problem is because the .jar files aren't added to the build path, but when I try to add them following [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) guide, I don't have any options after expanding "Build Path".  Did I set up my project incorrectly?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new Java Project.
2. Select the project, right click and select properties
3. From the list on the left, click Java Build Path, then click the "Add External JARs..." button.
4. Browse and select the jars from your file system.